# how to find top tracks and new releases using spotify api

Tags: spotify, libspotify

How to get the top tracks and new release album information from web api or `libspotify`? I tried `SPToplist` in `libspotify` but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Please be more specific. What did not work? What errors did you get?

Comment: [SPToplist toplistForCurrentUserInSession:aSession]

Comment: is there any web api url to get the top tracks and new releases ? please help

Answer (score 0):

### Top tracks

Look at the spshell example provided with libspotify. The toplist.c file has the toplist-specific parts, while spshell.c, spshell_win32.c and spshell_posix.c have the basic event-loop code that you'll need to use libspotify at all. At a minimum you're going to need to:

1. Create a session. (For which you'll need an app key.)
2. Log in.
3. Run an event loop on your main thread to call sp_session_process_events as needed.
4. Handle the notify_main_thread callback and use it to wake up your event loop so that it calls sp_session_process_events.
5. Call sp_toplist_browse_create to request a toplist, passing it a callback to invoke when the toplist is ready.
6. In your callback, you can access the results.

### New releases

I think for this you want to do a search for "tag:new". Have a look at search.c in the spshell example. Searching works similarly to browsing toplists.